# How to force a Python shell to re-import modules when running a buffer?

Tags: python

I'm using C-c C-c to send a buffer to a Python shell. The buffer has an import at the beginning. I found that if I modify the module I'm importing, it doesn't reflect the changes if I run the buffer again with C-c C-c (it seems the Inferior Python is doing the import only once).

How can I force the Python shell to import again the modules already called in the first run of the buffer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can explicitly reload a module like so:

```
import mymodule
import imp
imp.reload(mymodule)
```

Comment: For python >= 3.1 you should use importlib instead. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib).

Comment: [imp](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/imp.html) is deprecated since 3.4 and will be removed in 3.12, use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/importlib.html#module-importlib)

Answer (score 5):

This is my workflow. I set emacs to use ipython

```
(setq
 python-shell-interpreter "ipython3"
 python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt --pprint")
```

Then in ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-ipython_init.py I put the following:

```
ip = get_ipython()
ip.magic('load_ext autoreload')
```

Then I type this whenever I modify and want to reload my modules in ipython. I like this because it works for all modules and I don't have to worry about import dependencies.

```
%autoreload
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by modifying the python-run and forcing the Python process to restart:

```
;; Run python and pop-up its shell.
;; Kill process to solve the reload modules problem.
(defun my-python-shell-run ()
  (interactive)
  (when (get-buffer-process "*Python*")
     (set-process-query-on-exit-flag (get-buffer-process "*Python*") nil)
     (kill-process (get-buffer-process "*Python*"))
     ;; Uncomment If you want to clean the buffer too.
     ;;(kill-buffer "*Python*")
     ;; Not so fast!
     (sleep-for 0.5))
  (run-python (python-shell-parse-command) nil nil)
  (python-shell-send-buffer)
  ;; Pop new window only if shell isnt visible
  ;; in any frame.
  (unless (get-buffer-window "*Python*" t) 
    (python-shell-switch-to-shell)))

(defun my-python-shell-run-region ()
  (interactive)
  (python-shell-send-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (python-shell-switch-to-shell))

(eval-after-load "python"
  '(progn
     (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'my-python-shell-run)
     (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-r") 'my-python-shell-run-region)
     (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-h f") 'python-eldoc-at-point)))
```

http://lgmoneda.github.io/2017/02/19/emacs-python-shell-config-eng.html

Comment: Wonderful solution! You saved me few hours! Thank you!